# Running awk on file, with regular expressions

Tags: linux, perl, unix, awk

I would like to find all occurrences of INPUT in a file, JUST INPUT. I have the following, but it finds everything with INPUT*

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^INPUT/){print $i}}}'
```

I would like to support that though, so if I have INPUT* or INPUT? or INPUT. (any regular expression) instead of INPUT in the above, it should work for that.

Anyone know how to fix the above to do that? Thanks.

I'm trying to do the following in a perl script using $INPUT

```
`awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^$INPUT$/){print $i}}}' $file`
```

but I can't get it to work any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `grep`? with `-w` it searches `INPUT` not `*INPUT*` , with `-o` it gives only matched pattern as output, check `man grep`

Comment: Does calling awk from a perl script sound even vaguely like the right approach? Just pick one...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use backticks, then escape all dollar signs (assuming you have something, e.g., 'INPUT' in `$INPUT`)::

```
`awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(\$i~/^$INPUT\$/){print \$i}}}' $file | wc -l`;
```

awk can count the number of matches for you too (this one counts once one per line):

```
`awk '/\y$INPUT\y/{s++} END{print s}' $file`;
```

and using native Perl, which is recommended:

```
my $cnt;
open my $f, "<", "input" or die("$!");
while (<$f>) {
    $cnt++ while /\bINPUT\b/g;
}
close $f; 
print $cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you use is achored at the beginning `^` but not the end `$`. Try:

```
 awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^INPUT$/){print $i}}}'
```

If you want to match INPUT anywhere in the field, try:

```
 awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/INPUT/){print $i}}}'
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the following in a perl script using $INPUT
`awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^$INPUT$/){print $i}}}' $file | wc -l`;
but I can't get it to work any ides?

Comment: You're trying to invoke awk from inside a perl script? Why? Just use perl to open the file and scan the contents.